# Query logic, solution suggestion needed

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e9c97/59

There's my sample database. Tables created by WITH are simplified versions, in case I am working on, `is_paid` status is a set of many other conditions so it can't just be used from `orders` table. But output is the same

What I want to accomplish is find order details of first (`min(order_id)`) where all customer's orders were NOT paid OR `min(order_id)` for not paid order is smaller than `min(order_id)` for paid order.

Simplyfying: customer with paid order before not paid order is excluded from results.

`having min(onp.order_id) < min(op.order_id)` this part is nonsense without iterating within orders of single `customer_id` but how to do it?

The longer I am thinking about solution the less logic ways I'm trying..

Expected result should be:

```
order_id, customer_id, amount
3         101          30
5         102          15
11        104          31
15        105          11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the following query should get the job done :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT o.*, 
        MAX(is_paid) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_id) mp, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id, is_paid ORDER BY order_id) rn
    FROM orders o
) x WHERE is_paid = 0 AND rn = 1 AND mp = 0
```

The query uses a subquery with window functions to :

- check if any preceeding order was paid for this customer : `MAX(is_paid) OVER(...)`
- assign a sequence number to each record in groups of customer/status : `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)`

When no preceeding paid order exists and this is the fist unpaid record, then the record is filtered in by the outer query :

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rgLXTu3VysD3kRwBAQK3a4/1)** :

```
| order_id | customer_id | amount |
| -------- | ----------- | ------ |
| 3        | 101         | 30     |
| 5        | 102         | 15     |
| 11       | 104         | 31     |
| 15       | 105         | 11     |
```

Comment: I mentioned o.is_paid can't be used, I simplified it by including it here but I need to use these 2 additional tables - order_paid and order_not_paid

Comment: @sh4rkyy : oh, ok... Well I guess you should be able to change the `FROM` clause to integrate your two subqueries. In each subquery, just add a constant column `is_paid` with value `0` or `1` so it can be used in the outer query.

Comment: Like : `FROM (
    SELECT order_id, customer_id, 1 is_paid FROM orders WHERE is_paid = 1
    UNION ALL SELECT order_id, customer_id, 0 is_paid FROM orders WHERE is_paid = 0
)
`

Comment: NB : this would have been more straight forward if you had provided the *whole* dataset to start with. By seeing the data, we could possibly have found a way to avoid the use of two separated subqueries.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind to always provide full details. Also big thanks for the solution, I think I finally understood this function and am I missing something or `mp`  and partition by `is_paid` is redundant here and this query can be simplified to:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rgLXTu3VysD3kRwBAQK3a4/5 ?